# Tutorial for saving credentials into iPhone keychain?

Tags: iphone, sdk, keychain

I have been searching for UPDATED tutorials on how to access and save to the iPhone's keychain, but cant seem to find any that dont give me bucket-loads of errors, and use deprecated code.

If someone would please direct me into the right direction, that'll be awesome!

Thanks!

HERE IS THE ERROR I AM GETTING:

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_kSecValueData", referenced from:
      -[MainViewController viewDidLoad] in MainViewController.o
  "_kSecAttrAccount", referenced from:
      -[MainViewController viewDidLoad] in MainViewController.o
  "_kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked", referenced from:
      -[MainViewController viewDidLoad] in MainViewController.o
  "_kSecAttrAccessible", referenced from:
      -[MainViewController viewDidLoad] in MainViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_KeychainItemWrapper", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MainViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

2ND ERROR:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_KeychainItemWrapper", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MainViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit outdated, but we still use Apple's Generic [Keychain wrapper](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GenericKeychain/Listings/Classes_KeychainItemWrapper_m.html).

Here's also a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/dhoerl/1170641) where this class has been updated for ARC (I haven't used this personally, but it looks promising).

Good luck.

**EDIT**

Based on this error message, did you make sure to link the `Security` framework? If not, here's how:

1) Click on your project (blue bar on the left navigation)

2) Click on your target

3) Click the "Build Phases" tab

4) Click on the "Link with Binary Libraries" to expand

5) Click on the "Plus" in the bottom left

6) Add the framework titled `Security.framework`

**EDIT 2**

Did you make sure to `#import KeychainItemWrapper.h` into your `MainViewController`'s header or implementation file?

If so, can you verify that `KeychainItemWrapper.m` is indeed included in your Target's Build Phases -> Compile Sources? (If it isn't, you can add it via the "plus" on the bottom left).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much for the gist, exactly the errors I was getting are fixed in there! I'll try it out and report back!

Comment: Okay, here is another problem, what do I do about this? [check updated question]

Comment: Please see updated answer and let me know if this was the case.

Comment: Fixed some of the errors, forgot about the Security framework, haha. See my updated answer for new error.

Comment: Oh, MY GOD! Thank you, so much! Reason it wasn't working before was because I was compiling both .m and .h!

Comment: No prob. Good luck coding.